# how can I convert $("xx").load ( ... ) to $.mobile.loadPage( ... ) ; in jquery mobile ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

this is my actual script.

### HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="idSocial"></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$("#idSocial").load( vPagHome ,  
    {idioma : vLangLocal, filtremun: varFiltreMun, idpag: "idSocial" },
    function(){  
        console.log('success idSocial');  
});
```

I couldn't get to work with post params.
Thanks

Comment: Please specify much more concrete what your "couldn't get to work" exactly means.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery Mobile, you can use **[page events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)** or **[pagecontainer](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/)** events. If the code only needs to run once when the page is first loaded, use pagecreate:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#idSocial", function(){

});
```

If you want to run the code everytime the page is shown:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#idSocial", function(){

});
```